# How to find a lost laptop with Ubuntu installed?

Tags: security

Is there a way for me to track may lost laptop when there's no tracking tool (like prey) installed on it?

I tried to check the activity in my email but there's no trace.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, and anti-theft software only works if the person using your notebook is also an idiot.

Generally I would assume that the person that got hold of your notebook will remove or format the hard disc. There is also the idea to put a bios password onto the system but those can be circumvented with default passwords. Even prey will not help you there.

Prey only works if someone decides to boot into the system and get on-line using the operating system you installed but that would be the most stupid thing to do.  He would need to reset the admin password, then log into your system, set up wireless and go on-line. That is not very likely to happen.

Only thing you can do to protect your data is to use encryption, but you should consider the hardware gone. Unless the person finding it is someone that is willing to get it back to you (by finding a phone number or email address with, or stored in the notebook).

The only thing that would work is a hardware based solution: an independent SIM card in the notebook that can connect to the wireless and phone home when asked. That SIM could be impossible to remove without actually destroying the machine. But this too is something that should be created when you purchase it.